# Why on the Ender 3 does the hot end move too far on the Y axis after resuming print due to filament change?

Tags: creality-ender-3, slic3r

When printing a model I pause the print at around 80 % complete to insert a new spool of filament since I'm at the end of my last spool of Polymaker PETG. I used Slic3r Prusa edition to slice the model but I didn't put in for the print to change filament. Then when I did my pause to fix the new filament into the gear on the extruder so it continues to print and feed into the hot end. After fixing the new spool into the extruder and resuming the print it starts too far above the actual part not allowing it to actually continuing the print. Is there anything that I have to change in the G-code that will then resolve this or is this just a slicer error or a print error with the G-code that comes stock with the Ender 3. Or do I have to plug the printer into my computer to then fix the error in the G-code?

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! The Anet A8 was notoriously known for this issue also, the pause position was outside the bed limits causing the bed to hit a screw and the belt would then skip a few notches. Make sure that is not happening with your printer. *Disclaimer, I do not own an Ender 3.*

Comment: Ender 3 usually doesn't have this issue, but you can easily push the head off position as you load the new filament. DON'T TOUCH THE HEAD when changing filament.